# Table rowspan with ngFor Angular6

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6

[This is a working snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqyv2b)

I want the table to be like this:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered ">
 <thead>
  <tr id="first">
   <th id="table-header">
    <font color="white">No.</font>
   </th>
   <th id="table-header">
    <font color="white">Responsible team </font>
   </th>
   <th id="table-header">
    <font color="white">Task name</font>
   </th>
   <th id="table-header">
    <font color="white">Task description </font>
   </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <!-- 1 -->
   <tr id="second">
            <td rowspan="3" id="rowspan">1</td>
            <td rowspan="3" id="rowspan">Team1</td>
            <td>Description1</td>
            <td id="text">Application1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="second">
            <td>Description2</td>
            <td id="text">Application2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="second">
            <td>Description3</td>
            <td id="text">Application3</td>
          </tr>
      <tr>
        <tr id="third">
            <td rowspan="3" id="rowspan">2</td>
            <td rowspan="3" id="rowspan">Team2</td>
            <td>Description1</td>
            <td id="text">Application1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="third">
            <td>Description2</td>
            <td id="text">Application2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="third">
            <td>Description3</td>
            <td id="text">Application3</td>
          </tr>
      <tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

But I don't want to hardcode it, I want to use `*ngFor`

This is how I've tried:

```
<table class="table table-bordered ">
    <thead>
        <tr id="first">
            <th id="table-header">
                <font color="white">No.</font>
            </th>
            <th id="table-header">
                <font color="white">Responsible team </font>
            </th>
            <th id="table-header">
                <font color="white">Task name</font>
            </th>
            <th id="table-header">
                <font color="white">Task description </font>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let i of finalL ; let index = index">
            <tr id="second">
                <td id="rowspan">{{index + 1 }}</td>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let j of i">
                    <td id="rowspan">{{j}}</td>
                </ng-container>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But it is not working properly (you can see the difference on `stackblitz` link). How can I modify the code in order to obtain what I want? Thank you!

Comment: You should change ur algorithm to group your data by team before reaching the displaying part.

Comment: if your data is coming back as an observable or using data-source then you could return it as mentioned above using the .pipe(reduce()) method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can achieve this by treating the data like this:

In component **class**:

```
finalL = [
  ["Team1", "Description1", "Application1"],
  ["Team1", "Description2", "Application2"],
  ["Team1", "Description3", "Application3"],
  ["Team2", "Description1", "Application1"],
  ["Team2", "Description2", "Application2"],
  ["Team2", "Description3", "Application3"],
];

data() {
  // First find distinct teams and then filter information about him
  return this.finalL.map(x => x[0])
    .filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i)
    .map(x => ({ 
      name: x, 
      data: this.finalL.filter(y => y[0] === x)
    }));
}
```

and then on component **template**:

```
<table class="table table-bordered ">
  <thead>
    <tr id="first">
      <th id="table-header">
        <font color="white">No.</font>
      </th>
      <th id="table-header">
        <font color="white">Responsible team </font>
      </th>
      <th id="table-header">
        <font color="white">Task name</font>
      </th>
      <th id="table-header">
        <font color="white">Task description </font>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let i of data(); let index = index">
      <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
      <td>
        <tr *ngFor="let j of i.data">
          <td>{{ j[1] }}</td>
          <td>{{ j[2] }}</td>
        </tr>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Print of the result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfAsy.png)